# how to store file bytes in memory for files bigger than 2^32 bytes size

Tags: java, file

While working with encription of big files I've been forced to learn how this files are being read or written in/from the filesystem at a lower abstraction level than usual.

But there are some things that I can't understand at all being the main one why does `java.io.File.size` return a `long` value when, if it's possible, to persist it's bytes in memory I need to create a `byte array` whose constructor needs an `int` "parameter", e.g:

```java
File file = // ...
byte[] total = new byte[(int) file.size()];
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
...
```

while working with normal files I wouldn't even think about this since `int` can hold up to 2^32 values which would be, if I'm not mistaken, a bit more than 2GB.

I wonder why is this happening, if this is actually done this way or I'm misunderstanding Java's API and which alternatives I have to simplify this task.

PD: I know that by working with big files my interest doesn't rely on reading and completely maintaining it in memory since I'll easily raise an `OutOfMemoryException` but just a random use case.

Comment: _Don't_ read the entire file into memory. You'll need to use a `FileChannel` (NIO system) for files this large.

Comment: Why do you recommend `FileChannel`?

Comment: To answer OP's comment on a deleted question: File#size is a long because it makes sense to report filesizes larger than ~1.5Gb. But array indicies do not exist for the sake of representing file memory or large-scale systems, they exist to store contiguous data. Making indicies into `long`s would bring about a cascade of necessary bytecode changes, many of them detrimental to performance.

Comment: As for the question at hand, you don't typically want to load an entire file into memory anyhow; you're talking about gigabytes of memory used just to read a file! It's more efficient to read it piece-by-piece and gather the data you need from it.